# How to loop extraction of values from multiple raster files?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, raster

I have several raster files that I want to extract values from using the same set of GPS coordinates, and then save as a CSV file. This is my script:

```
x <- stack(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12, D13, D14) #D1 - 14 are raster layers I read into R using the raster() function

y <- numeric(14)

for(i in 1:14) {
  z <- unlist(x)
  y[i] <- extract(z[i], pts) #pts is a data frame containing only x and y coordinates
  y[i] <- cbind(pts, y[i])
  write.csv(y[,,i], file=sprintf('100', i
  ))
}
```

This gives me an error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"matrix", "data.frame"’

If I replace `for(i in 1:14) {` with `for(i in x) {`, it gives me the error:

> Error in for (i in x) { : invalid for() loop sequence

If I write `x <- c(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12, D13, D14)` and change the start of the loop to `for(i in x) {`, it gives me the error:

> Error in z[i] : invalid subscript type 'S4'

I'm not very familiar with the loop function so I'm not sure why it's giving me these errors. Is it possible to loop the extraction of values from several rasters using a set of GPS coordinates?

Edit:

I realised using `y <- numeric(14)` didn't make sense, so I tried this instead:

```
for(i in x) {
  value <- extract(i, pts)
  value <- cbind(pts, value)
  print(head(value))
  write.csv(value, file=paste('pts', i, 'csv', sep = '.'))
}
```

This works. However, only one CSV file containing the collective values is produced, and the file name does not follow "ptsi.csv". How do I fix it so that one CSV file per raster file is produced?

Comment: For your final loop, i suggest using `for(i in seq_along(x)){ value <- extract(x[i], pts`, keeping the remaining code the same. Your current output problem stems from the fact that `i` is not a numeric but a raster object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It makes sense now. But when I do that it gives me yet another error:  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"list", "tbl_df"’. I think the problem I'm facing is that I can't put the raster layers in a list, but I'm not sure how else do go about it.